# how do I use socket outside the scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Please suggest me the best way to access `socket` in different file. I am using socket.io.

index.js

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("message", onMessageRecieved)
})
```

message.js

```
    const onMessageRecieved = (payload) => {
        try { 
           console.log(socket.id)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

I know this is one way to do this.

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("message", (payload)=>onMessageRecieved(payload, socket))
})
```

But is there any other way. I need that because I am saving user data to socket like `socket.uid="ABC_NAME"` and want to access after receiving message.

Edited : I was trying to do the same using middleware. The below code works But got error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" while doing same with socket.

```
//a = socket, x= socket.on()
    let a = { 
        z : 1,
        x : function(m=1, n) {
            n(m, a)
        }
    }
    
    let e = (arg1, arg2) => {
        console.log(arg1, arg2.z);
    }
    
    a.x(2, e)
```

Comment: "*But is there any other way?*" - no. What's wrong with the solution you found? Notice that there are multiple connections and multiple sockets, so you always must explicitly pass a particular socket to your function to access it. There is no global variable that could be used for this.

Comment: Can we override on function inside middleware so that I don't have to do each time ? I am looking for another way for clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) like `onMessageRecieved(socket)`

index.js

```
io.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.on("message", onMessageRecieved(socket));
});
```

message.js

```
const onMessageRecieved = (socket) => {
  return (payload) => {
    try { 
      console.log(socket.id)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You. But, Is there anyway we can add extra argument while in socket middleware ? If you find any reference. Please share. I am looking for more clean code.